# dplyr percentage per group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, percentage

How can I calculate the percentage of a dataframe per each group of another column in dplyr?

`df` contains the following records

```
 A  target
   a    1
   b    0
   a    0
   a    1
```

This accomplishes the first part

```
df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise (n = n())
```

this the second

```
df %>%
  group_by(A, target) %>%
  summarise (n = n(), target_sum = sum(target))%>%
  filter(target == 1) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / target_sum)
```

but the quotient is taken from the from

In python/pandas

```
grouped = df_original.groupby(['A', 'target']).size()
df = (grouped / grouped.groupby(level=0).sum())
grouped = df.reset_index(name='percentageA')
groupedOnly = grouped[grouped.target == 1]
```

would achieve the desired computation with an result of:

```
a   1   0.666667
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You thought much too complicated. Try

```
df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise (mean(target))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#       A `mean(target)`
#       <fctr>          <dbl>
#    1      a      0.6666667
#    2      b      0.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `table` with `prop.table` in `R`

```
prop.table(table(df), 1)[,2]
#    a         b 
#0.6666667 0.0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way where you see how the data is flowing, but I like Alex's solution for efficiency.

```
df <- tribble(
  ~A , ~target,
  "a" ,   1,
  "b" ,   0,
  "a" ,   0,
  "a" ,   1
 )


df %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   mutate(n = n()) %>%
   group_by(A,target,n) %>%
   mutate(n_target = n()) %>%
   mutate(freq = n_target / n) %>%
   filter(target==1) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   distinct(A,target,freq)
```